# Sending data from JavaScript back into HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm building a basic website. One of the requirements is that the user enters a number, which is processed by JavaScript and then the processed data is output. Here is what I've come up with:

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Test Input</TITLE>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function testResults (form) {
    var TestVar = form.inputbox.value+1;
    // Here, I want to return TestVar as a h1 tag in HTML
}
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FORM NAME="myform" ACTION="" METHOD="GET">Enter something in the box: <BR>
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="inputbox" VALUE=""><P>
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" Value="Click" onClick="testResults(this.form)">
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

So that's what I want to do. I'm sorry if this is a stupid question; I'm new to web dev. Thanks

Comment: Don't forget to convert the input value to a number if you want to do numeric addition instead of string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

The easy/ugly way to this is :

Add H1 tag

```
<h1 id="title"></h1>
<FORM NAME="myform" ACTION="" METHOD="GET">Enter something in the box: <BR>
...
```

in your function :

```
function testResults (form) {
    var TestVar = form.inputbox.value+1;
    const title = document.querySelector('#title')
    title.innerText = TestVar
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `document.write('Text');` if that suits you, or you can make an invisible html element like div or something and then write to it.